# calling a pl/sql function with parameters from within a function in unix

Tags: unix, plsql

I have a function in my unix script which has a call to a pl/sql function. The unix function is called with values taken from user at runtime. These values are then needed to be passed to the pl/sql within the unix function along with some variables storing sql results. How do i call both the functions? How do i pass values?

Thanks in advance
Pranay

Answer (score 1):

You need an Oracle command interpreter to run PL/SQL code within a UNIX (bash?) program. You will need to call probably `sqlplus`, provide the corresponding credentials, and prepare a string with the SQL command corresponding to the PL/SQL procedure call.

You probably need something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "your sql sentence" > yourscript.sql
sqlplus user/pass@db @yourscript.sql
```

I know you said you use **ksh** but I don't know its syntax, and I am sure you can do something similar to what I posted.

Comment: I am using ksh and calling sqlplus. My code goes something like this: var1=`sqlplus -s name/pwd <<EOF select statement exit; EOF`  fun(){   sqlplus -s name/pwd <<EOF; getno(need to pass values here including var1) }

Comment: Thanks..But now i have got one little problem.  The called sql script prints the correct answer along with the following:  86044 PL/SQL procedure successfully completed. SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "2010/07/01..." - rest of line ignored. SP2-0734: unknown command beginning "2010/07/01..." - rest of line ignored. SP2-0042: unknown command "REL-LOC" - rest of line ignored.  Here 86044 is the number i require but the rest is also getting printed.  Please suggest
REL-LOC

Comment: @Pranay: let us look at your script and the way you are actually calling it.